Is it possible to log the stack trace where a variable changes?
I want to change a certain variable every second. But the same variable is changing on multiple places of them, and one of them is resulting in NaN. I can't seem to find out what exactly is causing that. Is there a way to log the stack trace where it changes? Take for example this code:


let foo = 0;

for (foo = 0; foo < 5; foo++) {
  // Do something
}

if (isNaN(foo)) {
  // Console.log the stack trace where the variable changes into NaN
}



Is it possible to do this in one, two or three lines without having to change too much logic or adding too much things in order for it to work? It is node.js-compatible, so it can be a NPM package if that's easier.

What you want is not a script or package, but the debugger function to watch a variable or conditional breakpoints

You tagged this question with typescript, but didn't give foo a type. Several (not all) causes of NaN surfacing as a result in JavaScript could be avoided by using TypeScript where you type all the variables that have anything to do with assignments to foo.

As far as I know, there is no such possibility, but in the new version of node, it is possible to get a stacktrace from the running function. Link

If foo is actually inside an object, you could make it a setter or a Proxy and capture new Error().stack on every set

If foo is in an object, you could wrap that object in a proxy that will report when certain properties change.  The proxy object below will call console.trace when a property is set with a key that was passed as part of the propsToWatch array.
function propertyWatcher<T extends object>(
  target: T,
  ...propsToWatch: (keyof T)[]
) {
  return new Proxy(target, {
    set: (tgt, key, value) => {
      if (propsToWatch.includes(key as keyof T)) {
        console.trace(`changing "%s" from %o to %o in %o`, key, (tgt as any)[key], value, tgt);
      }
      (tgt as any)[key] = value;
      return true;
    },
  });
}

Usage
const fooHost = { foo: 1 };

const fooHostProxy = propertyWatcher(fooHost, 'foo');

function setFooAndBar() {
  fooHostProxy.foo = 2;
}

setFooAndBar();

Output
changing "foo" from 1 to 2 in {foo: 1, bar: 1} 
set          @ main.ts:10
setFooAndBar @ main.ts:24


Yeah! That's what I was looking for! Thanks once again!

Depending on what version of node you are using I would just setup an Observable or whatever front end library I am using implementation of it.  You can find example of this all over stack.
How to observe value changes in JS variables
